# Looking for the Stuti (verses that praise) of Vedas and Upanishads

Tags: vedas, scripture, mantras

We know that the Vedas are considered most basic and important scripture of Hinduism. Vedas are believed to be words from Ishvara (अपौरुषेय). And the Upanishads are the part of Vedas which are full of spiritual knowledge and are known as Vedanta.

So, I am looking for praises (स्तुति) to Vedas & Upanishads which may have been composed by sages.

Comment: Do you want verses in the Vedas which praise the gods, or verses in other texts which praise the Vedas, or what?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan second case

Comment: Oh ok, you should edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: IMO - This is very Important and Excellent question, which i have tried to give answer(partially though).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I am here with providing partial answer of your question with " **Praising of Upanishads**" (upanishad Stuti , उपनिषद् स्तृती).

There is a chapter in **Shreemad Bhagvad purana  called "Veda Stuti"**  or Praising of Vedas. **See chapter 87 ,Verse 3 ,** (Gita press Gorakgpur version)  in which shree shuka deva is Praising Upanishadas. As -

> **सैषा हयुपनिषद ब्राह्मी पूर्वेषा पूर्वजै धृर्ता । श्रद्धया धारयेद**
>   **यस्तां क्षेमं गच्छेद किंश्चनः**
>
> Sesha Hyupanishad Brahmi Purvesham PurvajaiDhruta l  Shradhyaha
>   Dharayed Shkemam GacheeddaKincshanaha ll
>
> **Meaning** - Sanakadi Rishi ,who are ancestors of ancestors , accepted
>   this hign knowladge of Upanishadas ,which tells us about bhraman. Who
>   ever with devotion hear this ,gets freed from all the sins.

Comment: SB verse 10.87.14-41 are called Shruti Geeta